# Conditional button still executing action when false (not visible)

Tags: swift, swiftui, indexoutofboundsexception

I have a very simple SwiftUI app that shows a German word with its English translation. There is a "Next" button to cycle through a word list, which is swapped out for a "Done" button to restart the list if it is the last word.

Here is the relevant code:

```
struct ContentView: View {
  @State private var index = 0
  
  var body: some View {
    let english = Word.words[index].english
    let german = Word.words[index].german
    
    ZStack {
      Color("BackgroundColor")
        .ignoresSafeArea()
      VStack(spacing: 20) {
        Spacer()
        TitleView(word: german)
        CaptionView(word: english)
        Spacer()
        if index < Word.words.count - 1 {
          Button {
            index += 1
          } label: {
            Text("Next Word")
          }
        } else {
          Button {
            index = 0
          } label: {
            Text("Done")
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Tapping repeatedly on "Next" and "Done" works as expected: the word list is iterated over and then reset to the beginning.

However, when I tap quickly on these buttons, the app crashes with an `Index out of range` error. This happens when the "Done" button is displayed and tapped on. It also can occur when "Done" is not tapped on, but another area of the screen is tapped. As an example: I can alternate my taps between `Button` and `TitleWord`, and this will eventually cause the same crash. The only interactive components in the app are these two (conditional) buttons.

What is causing the index to become out of range? It seems like I have introduced a race condition, but I don't know how.

===

Update:

I fixed the problem with a simple check before incrementing `index`:

```
if index < Word.words.count - 1 {
  Button {
    if index < Word.words.count - 1 {
      index += 1
    }
  } label: {
    Text("Next Word")
  }
}
```

Since I am repeating the conditional, this tells me that there is indeed a race condition.

Answer (score 1):

SwiftUI refreshes a view when something is updated like when a @State property is updated, this isn’t done directly instead SwiftUI works in cycles so that all updates that has happened during a cycle will be seen in the next refresh of the UI.

So this is what happens when you press the buttons quickly, `index’ gets updated by more than 1 during a cycle and you risk getting an array out of index error.